# how to change value of object in array using setState with React

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, setstate

hello everyone good evening,

I have array of object set in state and i would like to change some object in the array.

so here is my array us you can see:

```
    const [CategoriesArr, setCategoriesArr] = useState([
    {
        image: anime,
        nameByCategories: "Aninate",
        allCard: [
            silverCard, blackCard
        ],
    },
    {
        image: vacation,
        nameByCategories: "Vacation",
        allCard: [
            blackCard, silverCard
        ],
    },])
```

i tried to change the `allCard` to: `allCard:blackCard, blackCard`

with this way:

```
setCategoriesArr([
{
    ...CategoriesArr[0],
    allCard: [
        silverCard, silverCard
    ]
}])
```

the problem is after the setState i get new array with changes that i want and also the last array so it means like this

```
  {
        image: anime,
        nameByCategories: "Aninate",
        allCard: [
            blackCard, blackCard
        ],
    },
    {
        image: vacation,
        nameByCategories: "Aninate",
        allCard: [
            silverCard, blackCard
        ],
    },
  {
        image: anime,
        nameByCategories: "vacations",
        allCard: [
            blackCard, silverCard
        ],
    },
```

i would like to understand i can i get new array exact like that:

```
    const [CategoriesArr, setCategoriesArr] = useState([
{
    image: anime,
    nameByCategories: "Aninate",
    allCard: [
        silverCard, blackCard
    ],
},
{
    image: vacation,
    nameByCategories: "Vacation",
    allCard: [
        blackCard, blackCard
    ],
},])
```

pleas.

i hope you guys going to help me :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a simple way to do it.

```
const updateCategoryList = (id) => {
  const newCategories = CategoriesArr.map(cate => {
    if (cate.nameByCategories === id) { // <= id can be "Aninate" or anything you want
      cate.allCard[silverCard, silverCard]
      return cate;
    }
  })
  setCategoriesArr(newCategories)
}
```

you can use this updateCategory function with event handler or with other functions or components you want.

I hope you find a solution!

Comment: The "return cate" should be outside the scope of the If condition, if not, you will only return the modified object and the rest of the array will be undefined since you don't return a value on the map function

Answer (score 0):

The issue is setter method (from `useState` hook) is not like `setState` in class components that merge the changes to the existing state.

By using the callback function of the setter gives you the `previousState` to merge the new changes to and return (in your case change is only a property of the first item in the state).

This one would also work.

```
   setCategoriesArr((prevValue) => {
      return prevValue.map((item, itemIndex) => {
        if (itemIndex === 0) {
          return { ...item, allCard: ["silverCard", "silverCard"] };
        } else {
          return item;
        }
      });
    });
```

Code sandbox => https://codesandbox.io/s/runtime-shadow-2bbxh?file=/src/App.js